# How to use mongoDB aggregartion in server side nodejs function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to `nodejs`, I am trying to get the all duplicate documents in a collection in `mongoDB` for that I have tried the following query in mongo shell

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          ProductName: "$ProductName"
        },
        uniqueIds: {
          $addToSet: "$_id"
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        count: {
          $gte: 2
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        count: -1
      }
    }
])
```

### In mongo shell result:

```
    {
            "_id" : {
                    "ProductName" : "Sony Mobile"
            },
            "uniqueIds" : [
                    ObjectId("5728ce42a069270e00e59910"),
                    ObjectId("5728cde6a069270e00e5990e")
            ],
            "count" : 2
    },

   {
            "_id" : {
                    "ProductName" : "Nokia Mobile"
            },
            "uniqueIds" : [
                    ObjectId("5728ce42a069270e00e59920"),
                    ObjectId("5728cde6a069270e00e5990f")
            ],
            "count" : 2
    }
```

In mongo shell it gaves the result what i want correctly, but i tried the same query in nodejs server side function like below

```
  Company.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          Proname: "$Proname"
        },
        uniqueIds: {
          $addToSet: "$_id"
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        count: {
          $gte: 2
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        count: -1
      }
    }
]).then(function (dupProds) {
    console.log("ALL DUPLICATE PRDCTS : " + JSON.stringify(dupProds));
  })
};
```

It shows me an error that Compnay.aggregate(...).then is not a function, I tried in different ways but no use, now how can get the result same as like I got in mongoshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exec` instead of `then` for *mongoose* and in *callback* function  parameters `error` then `result`.

```
Company.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          Proname: "$Proname"
        },
        uniqueIds: {
          $addToSet: "$_id"
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        count: {
          $gte: 2
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        count: -1
      }
    }
]).exec(function (err,dupProds) {
    if(err) {
      // return err;
    }
    console.log("ALL DUPLICATE PRDCTS : ", dupProds);
    // return dupProds
  })
};
```

Actually `then` worked on *promise* so if you want to use `then` you need to *promising*. so can use like

`aggregate([{..}]).exec().then(function(result){..})`

where `aggregate([{..}]).exec()` return *promise*

Answer (score 1):

You need call `exec` before `then`:

```
  Company.aggregate(params).exec().then(function (dupProds) {
    console.log("ALL DUPLICATE PRDCTS : " + JSON.stringify(dupProds));
  })
};
```

[ http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec ]